# Pass data from page 1-2-3-4... in PHP (without sessions/cookies)

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, serialization, http-headers

I know that sessions are probably the most efficient way to do this, and I've found a number of answers on how to do it with those, however for the sake of this project I'm not allowed to do so. What I'm currently doing is using `http_build_query` to pass the info from `$_POST` and a separate array to the next page using the following code.

```
    if ($login[$user] == $pass) {
                            $qstr = http_build_query(
            array(
                'products_array' => $products,
                'quantity' => $_POST['quantity']
            )
    );
      header('Location: display_invoice.php?' . $qstr);
```

This works and I can access the arrays in the `$_GET array` after I redirect them, but if I try to use the same code to pass the information again to the next page, the `$_GET array` is empty. Could I get some input on how to pass the array information from page 1 to the final page without the use of sessions or cookies?

Comment: Thanks for all the reply's I'll look into the documentation for all of your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `serialize()` your data like this example. In the page `1.php` you have an array that is sent through the `header(Location:...)` to page `2.php`. In `2.php` you can see the received array and you send the info to `3.php` through a link. And in `3.php` you can see the array that come from `1.php`

Try with the example

**1.php**

```
<?php

    $bond = array (
    'Sean Connery' => 'Dr. No',
    'George Lazenby' => 'On Her Majesty\'s Secret Service',
    'Roger Moore' => 'Live and Let Die',
    'Timothy Dalton' => 'The Living Daylights',
    'Pierce Brosnan' => 'GoldenEye',
    'Daniel Craig' => 'Casino Royal'
    );

$info = serialize($bond);

header('Location: 2.php?values=' . $info);

?>
```

**2.php**

```
<h1>Page 2</h1>
<?php

$values = $_GET['values'];
$info = unserialize($values);

foreach($info as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . ' - ' . $value . '<br>';
}   

?>

<p>
<a href="<?php echo '3.php?values=' . urlencode(serialize($info)); ?>">Send values to 3.php</a>
</p>
```

**3.php**

```
<h1>Page 3</h1>
<?php

$values = $_GET['values'];
$info = unserialize($values);

foreach($info as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . ' - ' . $value . '<br>';
}   

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store them in an a hidden array as JSON `json_encode()` then restore them with `json_decode()`

Store $_GET in page 1:

```
<input name="oldget" value="<?= json_encode($_GET)?>">
```

Fetch $_GET in page 2:

```
<?php $old_get = json_decode($POST['get'])?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your array change you $_POST to $_REQUEST. This way you will get the quantity for both post and get

$_REQUEST is an associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE

[Here is the documentation on it](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)